# How to correctly isolate states in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, design-patterns, react-hooks, architecture

> I want my parent component state to be updated by its children
> independently, without the parent doing micromanagement and being
> aware of variables modified by its children.  I'm abstracting these
> modifications with a single method `onIssueDataChanged`. The modified
> `state` object will then be transferred to GraphQL, so no need for the
> parent to know what's in it.  My problem, is that children cannot call
> `onIssueDataChanged` in `useEffect`.

Here's the concrete problem:

I have a form `IssueFieldsForm` that handles the saving of an object called `issue`.

The object has a gallery of pictures included, the pictures can be added, removed or selected as the main issue picture. That logic is isolated in a separate component called `GalleryComp`, and the info is stored in a non-persistent issue field called `attachmentsMeta`.

My problem is that I want to isolate handling of the `attachmentsMeta` in `GalleryComp` and have in `IssueFieldsForm` a generic method I called `onIssueDataChanged` which takes only changed values and updates the `issue` variable state with it. That seems hard to do since I initialize an `attachmentsMeta` state in `GalleryComp` with the current `attachments` in the `useEffect` hook, but I cannot send that back to the `issue` state object in the parent.

```
export default function GalleryComp(props) {
    const {issue, onItemsChanged} = props
    const [attachmentsMeta, setAttachmentsMeta] = useState({
        images: [],
        attachmentsAttributes: {},
        mainAttachmentIndex: 0
    })

    useEffect(() => {
        const newAttachmentsMeta = {...attachmentsMeta}
        newAttachmentsMeta.images = []
        logger.debug('attachments cont before concat: ', newAttachmentsMeta.images.length)
        newAttachmentsMeta.images = unionBy(issue.attachments, issue.attachmentsMeta?.images, 'url')
        logger.debug('after concat: ', newAttachmentsMeta.images.length)
        newAttachmentsMeta.mainAttachmentIndex = issue.mainAttachmentIndex
        logger.debug('displaying attachments: ', newAttachmentsMeta)

        setAttachmentsMeta(newAttachmentsMeta)
    }, [issue?.attachmentsMeta])
```

That is a problem for me because if I don't do any change in the attachments, `onIssueDataChanged` will never be called to update the variable `issue.attachmentsMeta` with the initial `attachments`. Leading me to lose my original attachments on save (since they were not transferred to my single source of truth `issue.attachmentsMeta`).

On the other hand, if I initialize `issue.attachmentsMeta` in the parent component, I lose the elegance of having each component handle its own variables.

p.s: Obviously I cannot call `onIssueDataChanged` in the effect since it would trigger a state change and enter an infinite loop.

How would you do this?

Comment: I feel like you're kind of overthinking your problem statement. `issue.attachmentsMeta` is only changed from the parent component, that will update the internal state of `GalleryComp` which is `attachmentsMeta`. If you want to update `issue.attachmentsMeta` with initial `attachments`, you can remove `issue?.attachmentsMeta` in dependency list of `useEffect`. If you want to initialize `attachmentsMeta` with `issue`, you can modify `useState` with a default value from `issue`.

Comment: Ok my post could be unclear (I upvoted your comment since it made me enhance my question). I want `issue` in the parent component to be updated by its children like `GalleryComp` without the parent doing micro-management and being aware of variables modified by its children. I'm abstracting these modifications with a single method `onIssueDataChanged`.
The modified `issue` object will then be transferred to GraphQL, so no need for the parent to know what's in it. 
My problem, is that children cannot call onIssueDataChanged in useEffect

Comment: If that is the case, why do you pass `issue` to `GalleryComp`?

Comment: Because GalleryComp is responsible for managing the attachments of issue, it only handles the field attamchmentsMeta, but at the end, it's the form (the parent) that validates data, sends it to the backend and manages onChange events. The parent doesn't need to know the details of what changed, it only needs to be notified of a change to do its routines

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by exporting an `initGalleryData` function from `GalleryComp` and using it in the form. This way, details are hidden in the child.

> This way, I can reuse the Gallery Component with any object, by simply
> not forgetting to initiate the object and by providing an
> 'onDataChange' modificator
>
> This code is used in the [weally.org](https://weally.org) project, gathering people for
> protests online by concens

```
export default function GalleryComp(props) {
    const {issue, onItemsChanged} = props
    const attachmentsMeta = issue.attachmentsMeta

    const {t} = useTranslation('complaintList')


    function setMainAttachmentIndex(index) {
        const attachmentsMetaCopy = {...attachmentsMeta}
        attachmentsMetaCopy.mainAttachmentIndex = index
        onItemsChanged({attachmentsMeta:attachmentsMetaCopy})
    }

    function onAttachmentRemoveAction(attachmentId, removed) {
        const attachmentsModified = {...attachmentsMeta}
        let attr = attachmentsModified.attachmentsAttributes[attachmentId]
        if (!attr) {
            attr = {deleted: removed}
            attachmentsModified.attachmentsAttributes[attachmentId] = attr
        } else {
            attr.deleted = removed
        }
        onItemsChanged({attachmentsMeta: attachmentsModified})
    }

    if (attachmentsMeta.images?.length === 0)
        return <Divider style={sx.descDivider}/>

    return (
        <>
            <Gallery attachments={attachmentsMeta} onRemoveAction={onAttachmentRemoveAction}
                     selectedIndex={attachmentsMeta.mainAttachmentIndex}
                     onSelectionChange={setMainAttachmentIndex}/>
            <Divider style={sx.descDivider}/>
        </>
    )

}

export function initGalleryData(issue) {
    issue.attachmentsMeta = {
        images: [...issue.attachments],
        attachmentsAttributes: {},
        mainAttachmentIndex: 0
    }
}
```

I then just have to initialize the needed fields at component creation.

```
export default function IssueFieldsForm(props) {
    const {t} = useTranslation('complaintList')
    const {
        issue,
        onIssueDataChanged,
        markers,
        onMarkersChanged,
        onMarkerSelected,
        setPlaceMarkersDisplayed,
        placeMarkersDisplayed
    } = props

    initGalleryData(issue);
    const [validationState, setValidationState] = useState(new ValidationResult())
//...
return (
        <Card sx={sx.issueFieldsForm} id="IssueFieldsForm">
            <Grid item sx={sx.item} ref={scrollTopRef}>
                <Typography variant={'h5'} sx={sx.header}>{t('edit.header')}</Typography>
            </Grid>
//...
<GalleryComp issue={issue} onItemsChanged={onIssueDataChanged}/>
//...
)
```